# Spring Batch test case with multiple data sources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch Classifier to test for which I've defined this test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BatchConfiguration.class })
class CsvOutputClassifierTest {

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> createRequestForProposalWriter;

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> createRequestForQuotationWriter;

    private final CsvOutputClassifier csvOutputClassifier = new CsvOutputClassifier(
            createRequestForProposalWriter,
            createRequestForQuotationWriter);

    @Test
    void shouldReturnProposalWriter() {
        ...
    }
```

The batch configuration class has this constructor:

```java
    public BatchConfiguration(
            final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            @Qualifier("oerationalDataSource") final DataSource oerationalDataSource,
            final DwhFileManager dwhFileManager,
            final OperationalRepository operationalRepository)
```

And these beans:

```java
    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> createRequestForProposalWriter(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['startDate']}") String startDate) {
        FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData>();
        ...
        return writer;
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> createRequestForQuotationWriter(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['startDate']}") String startDate) {
        FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData>();
        ...
        return writer;
    }
```

Running the test class I'm not able to trigger the first test method as I'm getting:

```
Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="oerationalDataSource")}
```

In fact, I defined two different data sources, one for the 'operational' data and the 'app' for Spring Batch persistency:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties defaultDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource defaultDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("aggr.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties oerationalDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("aggr.datasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource oerationalDataSource(
            @Qualifier("oerationalDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties oerationalDataSourceProperties) {
        return oerationalDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate operationalJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("oerationalDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

In @SpringBatchTest documentation it is reported that just one DataSource should be found or it should be marked as Primary:

*It should be noted that JobLauncherTestUtils requires a org.springframework.batch.core.Job bean and that JobRepositoryTestUtils requires a javax.sql.DataSource bean. Since this annotation registers a JobLauncherTestUtils and a JobRepositoryTestUtils in the test context, it is expected that the test context contains a single autowire candidate for a org.springframework.batch.core.Job and a javax.sql.DataSource (either a single bean definition or one that is annotated with org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary).*

But I have it. So how to fix it?

**Update #1**

Thanks to @Henning's tip, I've changed the annotations as follows:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest(args={"--mode=custom", "--startDate=2022-05-31T01:00:00.000Z", "--endDate=2022-05-31T23:59:59.999Z"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BatchConfiguration.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class, LocalFileManager.class, AggregatorRepository.class })
@ActiveProfiles({"integration"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Where:

- @SpringBootTest is needed to avoid 'Failed to determine a suitable driver class exception'
- args is needed to provide the required parameters to the batch

But still having this exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.createRequestForProposalWriter' defined in BatchConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter]: Factory method 'createRequestForProposalWriter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: text
```

raised in the implementation of:

```java
@StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<CsvData> createRequestForProposalWriter(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['startDate']}") String startDate)
```

as the parameter 'startDate' is null.

In my naivety I assumed that I could test in isolation the classifier with something  like that:

```java
    @Test
    void shouldReturnProposalWriter() {
        CsvData csvData = create-some-fake-data
        CsvOutputClassifier csvOutputClassifier = new CsvOutputClassifier(
                createRequestForProposalWriter,
                createRequestForQuotationWriter);
        ItemWriter itemWriter = csvOutputClassifier.classify(csvData);        
        some-assert-about-itemWriter-properties
    }
```

So now the question is: how to correctly test the classifier?

Answer (score 1):

You need to list `DataSourceConfiguration` as argument of `@ContextConfiguration`, i.e. your test class should start like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BatchConfiguration.class, DataSourceConfiguration.class })
class CsvOutputClassifierTest {
  ...
}
```

The `DataSourceConfiguration` is currently not known within the test as you didn't declare it as part of the context or enabled classpath scanning in any form.

Comment: I was able to make a step further but got another error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: ... Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I've added:

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

and:

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    }

But it doesn't work

Comment: Adding: 

@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource")

allows to go further the previous error but now I got:

Parameter 3 of constructor in BatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'DwhFileManager' that could not be found.

I don't know how to inject it

Comment: For the test you need to supply some database. Either an in-memory databse like H2 or a full database that could be started with testcontainers. You need to set the database properties for the test accordingly.

Comment: I have it, it runs without problems with the other tests

Comment: +1 to what @Henning said. Please do not add code in comments. You can edit the question and added formatted code there. In order to use `@SpringBatchTest`, your test context should contain a datasource bean. The next error you are getting is not related to Spring Batch, but is similar to the initial one that was related to the ds: `a bean of type 'DwhFileManager' that could not be found`. You need to add the configuration class that contains that bean definition in `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {.. })`.

Comment: The NPE happens because `startDate` is not passed as a job parameters from `@SpringBootAnnoation` as you expect, I don't see a job being tested in what you shared. `So now the question is: how to correctly test the classifier?`: the classifier is a scoped component, you create use a regular unit test for that class  and use the `StepScopeTestUtils` to test the classifier, see the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components.